# Git Reverting to Previous Version with Dev, Staging and Master branches

Tags: git, phpstorm

So, say I made some changes to a file that I shouldn't have, then pushed that file up to Development and Staging branches, but Master branch is still fine.

I want to revert to a previous version on Dev and Staging so that it does not keep the history of me editing this file.

Additionally, there has been another edit to this file after mine that I would like to keep:

A (where I want to revert to) -- B(my change) -- C(my change) -- D (change I want to keep)

So Basically I want to have A -- D

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you now you have

```
D
|
C
|
B
|
A
```

And you want to have

```
D
|
A
```

So, as first you checkout to HEAD of this branch - you have to be on D commit. And then call rebase interactive to commit before commit A by method

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

You will see list of commit from D to A with their hashcodes and pick word

```
pick f5b61e4 D
pick 65286fb C
pick 7b32f8c B
pick b8a35c6 A
```

Modify their to

```
pick f5b61e4 D
pick b8a35c6 A
```

and save message as in commit

You will have

```
D
|
A
```

If it will not resolve your problem, please will describe your problem more clarity